# sending emails from an azure web app

Tags: azure, email, azure-storage-queues

Im creating a webjob to place jobs (emails with attachments) in a storage queue.  What are the options available for sending emails from azure ? (can I use standard system.net.mail myself or do I have to use a third party).  Also, If my email has attachments (one or more reports) how Do I get around the message size limit in storage queue if the attachments are large ?.  Ive just started the groundwork for this project so any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to use a third party: Azure doesn't support sending mail. Azure promotes using SendGrid (and even enables you to get an account through the Azure portal). For the attachments: I would put them in BlobStorage and reference them in the message you put on the storage queue.

Comment: @RickvandenBosch That should probably be an answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a third party: Azure doesn't support sending mail. Azure promotes using SendGrid (and even enables you to get an account through the Azure portal). It even enables you to get a Free account (that, if I'm not mistaking, you cannot get from the SendGrid website anymore).

[image: Create SendGrid account from Azure Portal]

**Attachments**
I would put the attachments in BlobStorage and reference them in the message you put on the storage queue. This way you can get them from storage and attach them to the email in the worker that processes the message.